# need help answering question about sql data integrity

Tags: sql

The question is:

> For   your    final   designed    database,   find    a   scenario    in  which   a   relatively  prominent   business    data
>   integrity can not be  ensured by  your    current primary keys    and foreign keys,   nor by  adding  directly
>   more  of  such    keys    or  check   clauses in  the created tables.
>   In    other   words,  the data    integrity   ensured by
>   the   keys    within  the database    may not be  enough  to  ensure  all the data    integrity   within  the business
>   context.
>
> Write a   SQL statement   that    will    determine   if  such    a   problem exists  or  not,    and where,  for any
>   given state   of  the database.

I am not too sure what this question is asking or how to approach it.

Need help writing a sql code for this question.

Comment: That's a weird question.

Comment: yes, its for my assignment and my tutor cant help.. im unsure what it is even asking or how to write and sql for it

Comment: it is a question from an assignment, i had to create a database of a booking system where a client and book a coach for activities like swimming, tennis etc

Comment: prior to that question i had 4 questions where i had to write sql scripts on the following
1) for a given coach and date list all clients who have a booking
2) List all the coaches and their respective total number of coaching hours that are ever booked for.
3) for a given date list all the coaches booked, corresponding time booked, venue details and client details
4) for a given timeslot, given date and given training item(ie. swimming) list all the coaches who have not been booked and are available

Comment: Is this specific to MS SQL Server?

Comment: we had to fill in the tables with our own data

Comment: Here's a question to get you started down the right track - can you enforce "bookings must be in the future" with a constraint within your chosen database?

Comment: @liam clarke, i understand that, however the question is asking me to write to sql script to determine if there is a problem, i know how to constraint to the date to make sure it is in the future but i am unsure on what my sql script should be

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is asking you to define some business logic that cannot be encoded in the database. However, it then wants you to find conflicts that could occur because the business logic is not encoded in the database. This second part seems to be in conflict with the first, but not necessarily.

An example based on your previous assignment would be if a coach is suddenly sick and there are too few additional coaches to cover the booked clients, or some coaches are not qualified to replace the sick coach, or had previous conflicts with certain clients and therefore can't be assigned to those clients. Therefore, some training bookings must be cancelled.

The decision on which are best to cancel may be difficult or impossible to code in SQL, but you can use SQL to verify that all of the sick coach's slots have either been filled by others or cancelled after the external business logic is applied.

**EDIT:** I think the above scenario fits the question's requirement that you can't find the conflicts (such as clients that don't like certain coaches) in your existing foreign key relationships, but you can verify that the external logic is consistent with the final requirements (all slots accounted for).

**Perhaps a better example is the traveling salesman problem: It is difficult to code the least cost routing in SQL, but it's easy to verify that all cities have been visited.**

Answer (score 0):

The scenarios where every row can have variable number of attributes and each attribute can have variable number of datatypes, is generally modeled using EAV datamodel. [EAV wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Here, attribute can have variety of values and so, we cannot enforce check constraint always. In some scenarios, if attributes finite list is not available, we cannot have foreign key for attributeID.

This datamodel is popular in the medical history datamodel, where every patient can have different kinds of symptoms.

May be this can be an example for a scenario, where data integrity cannot be completely enforced.